# How do I fix a wooden fence that has shifted and won't close?

Tags: fence, backyard

There's no visible sag so I don't even know what part to adjust, or how. It used to fit but in the past few weeks has become misaligned so that it won't close. Nothing seems loose or moveable[image]

Comment: Pictures will help a lot.  Imagine you talking about a gate not closing, than a fence it is attached to.   We need to know the misalignment type(sag, twist, other).  Size of gate and what is not closing(gate itself or just the catch).

Comment: How has the weather been? Has there been rain or snow recently, or perhaps freezing of the soil?

Comment: You shall check the plumpness of both the fence posts and the door which may have distorted.

Comment: Are the hinges adjustable?

Comment: Yes, it's the gate. It seems to have shifted left to right but nothing seems loose. The gate itself won't close. There has been rain lately, yes

Comment: @r13: All the parts seem chubby enough in the photo -- maybe he should check how much they deviate from the vertical -- there's probably a word for that...

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri - 'deviate from the vertical' == 'out of plumb' :)

Comment: why is the gate not closing? ... where is the interference?

Comment: Top-left post is suspiciously out-of-line with the top brace beam.  It looks shifted right which would lower the right side of the gate,  which would make the slider to low. Seems that the left post needs to be shifted left at the top, raising the right side of the gate

Answer (score 2):

**Tighten the turnbuckle?**

If the gate is bottoming out at the low corner because it is sagging because of the Pull of the Earth, that cable and turnbuckle can hoist the sag back up.  It is right there.  You already have it installed.  It is free to try!

https://www.popularmechanics.com/home/outdoor-projects/a26127/do-repair-kits-for-wood-gates-actually-work/

> The cable runs diagonally across the gate with the turnbuckle in the
> center. Tightening the turnbuckle tensions the cable, lifting the low
> corner of the gate.